# Using the marked library - TypeError: marked.parse is not a function

Tags: reactjs, javascript-marked

I am buiding a simple markdown previewer in JS

I have:

- Installed the library by running `npm i marked` in the app folder (I double checked the nodes_package folder and a marked folder was indeed created)
- Added `import marked from "marked"` at the top of my `App.js` file
- As per suggested in the Marked documentation’s “advanced” section, used the `marked.parse(string)` function

When I try to run the app, I get:

> TypeError: marked.parse is not a function

Comment: I had some help - the key was to add the script to the index.html file, and to set the ```/* global marked */```flag at the top of the App.js - looks like something was off when importing

Answer (score 0):

you can use `marked` just like this:

Import marked

`import marked from 'marked';`

Then call the function in your component:

`marked('# Markdown');`

##### Here is the example:

```js
// app.jsx
import marked from "marked"

const html = marked('# Marked in React\n\nRendered by **marked**.');

const App = () => {
    return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
}
```

Though it generate the result in `html format`, so we need to parse it by using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) of react.

Answer (score 0):

I had some help - the key was to add the script to the index.html file, and to set the `/* global marked */` flag at the top of the App.js - looks like something was off when importing